# Lemmatizer supporting german language (for commercial and research purpose)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, linguistics

I am searching for a lemmatization software which:

- supports the german language
- has a license that allows it to be used for commercial and research purpose. LGPL license would be good.
- should preferably be implemented in Java. Implementations in other programming languages would also be OK.

Does anybody know about such a lemmatizer?

Regards,

**UPDATE**: Hi Daniel, At first, thank you for the great work you are providing with the LanguageTool.

We would like to index german Texts into elasticsearch (ES) and pre-analyze the texts using either
 an ES-built-in german stemmer (please see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html) 
or 
the following plugin https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-analysis-baseform. The latter uses your morphology file under http://www.danielnaber.de/morphologie/morphy-mapping-20110717.latin1.gz and that is why I thought you maybe have some evaluation data in order to know what is the trade-off when using the lemmatization based on your morphology file instead of an ES-built-in stemmer. Do you maybe have some figures in terms of precision/ coverage of your german morphology? Or comparative data with the german stemmers used in Elasticsearch?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org) can do that (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of LanguageTool), it's available under LGPL and implemented in Java. You could use [GermanTagger.tag()](https://languagetool.org/development/api/org/languagetool/tagging/de/GermanTagger.html#tag%28java.util.List%29), the result can have more than one reading (as language is often ambiguous), and each reading's `AnalyzedToken` finally has a lemma.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I will evaluate the lemmatizer and give you feedback if you are interested.

Comment: @Horace Sure, please let me know how it works for you.